# Array declaration of an unsigned char

Tags: c

I have a problem which states that an `unsigned char` array stores `unsigned int`'s, with each `int` using 3 bytes only.

Why would my teacher initialize the vector like this `unsigned char s[]="\x12\x34\x78\x9A\xBC\xDE\xFF"` and not just simply with ints?  I believe that the numbers are represented in hexadecimal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because your teacher is being stingy with his memory usage, probably.

By using a "packed" array of `unsigned char`s, each 24-bit integer can be stored using just 24 bits (assuming an 8-bit `char`, whhich is not very controversial here I hope).

Note that also chosing to use string notation makes it more compact in the source (although less readable); the first integer is `"\x12\x34\x78"`, which in array notation would be `0x12, 0x34, 0x78` which is longer due to the commas (and spaces, which of course could be removed unlike the commas).

A possible compromise could be to use the fact that in C adjacent string literals are concatenated, and write each 24-bit number as a string of its own:

```
unsigned char s[] = "\x12\34\x78" "\x9a\xbc\xde";
```

That makes it easier to spot the boundaries of each number, but of course the repeated quotes take up space.

You can extract a single integer like so:

```
unsigned int unpack24(size_t index)
{
  if(index >= (sizeof s) / 3)
    return 0;
  const unsigned int hi  = s[3 * index];
  const unsigned int mid = s[3 * index + 1];
  const unsigned int low = s[3 * index + 2];
  return low | (mid << 8) | (hi << 16);
}
```

Note that the above assumes big-endian numbers, so the first one would unpack to `0x123478`; I can't know that this is correct of course.

Comment: How would you make an integer again? As in "unpack" it?

Comment: Thank you very much!That really helped me a lot :)